# Can I change Task parent on running task?

Tags: java, vmware, vmware-sdk

Is there a way in java to change 'parentTaskKey' of TaskInfo data object?

I noticed in vmware sdk 5.5 documentation that this field "*Need not be set", which I don't comprehend.

[vmware sdk documentation](https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/converter-sdk/conv51_apireference/vim.TaskInfo.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parentTaskKey is set based on what kind of task was run and what object it was run on.  You can probably set it if you create a task, but for a running task you cannot change that property.

"Need not be set" means that the value can be NULL and it is not required.